# How to drop rows from multiple tsv files comparing with a list in a faster way?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have multiple tsv files with thousands of rows inside it. And I also have a large list. I want to compare my tsv files first two columns with a list items. If tsv files columns value matched with a list value then drop that row from tsv files. I want it in the fastest way.

tsv1:

```
3  Dave    68
8  Jerry   34
1  Alice   24
5  Frank   30
```

tsv2:

```
2  Bob     42
7  Tom     54
5  Frank   30
1  Alice   24
```

my_list:

```
 [{'id': '1', 'name': 'Alice'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'Bob'}, {'id': '8', 'name': 'Jerry'}]
```

Expected output:

tsv1:

```
3  Dave    68
5  Frank   30
```

tsv2:

```
7  Tom     54
5  Frank   30
```

I have done this so far but it takes a lot of time to iterate multiple files and I did not get my expected output.

```
my_list = []
for row in tags_from_all_media:
    my_list.append((row["id"],row["name"]))

counts = Counter()      # hold counts of each first two value pairs
data = defaultdict(list)  # hold all data from all files

for tsv in [tsv1, tsv2]:
    with open(tsv) as f_tsv:
        for row in f_tsv:
            split = list(map(str.strip, row.split('\t')))
            key = tuple(split[:2])  # first and second column values
            counts[key] += 1
            data[tsv].append((key, row))


for tsv, key_rows in data.items():
    with open(tsv, 'r+') as f_tsv:
        for key, row in key_rows:
            if key not in my_list:
                f_tsv.write(row)
```

Comment: Why do you have `counts`? This seems to have no purpose and just makes everything slower.

Comment: Which output did you get instead of what you expected?

Comment: i got an output in which matched values were not dropped out from tsv files.

Comment: i want an output like,  If tsv files columns value matched with my list value then drop that row from tsv files as i already showed the output file above. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: `counts` hold counts of each first two value pairs. If you can do it without `counts`  please tell me. I actually dont know how to get my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

tsv files are text files. Whatever way, you will have to read and write them, which should be the most time consuming task. BTW, to remove values, you should use `w` mode to truncate a file rather than `r+` which keeps the end of the file...

Assuming that they are small enough, you can probably load each one in memory, but it is no use loading them all.

Finally, it is much quicker to search values from a set than from a list (there are different containers for a reason...)

So IMHO the best improvement to your code is to use a set:

```
my_list = set()
for row in tags_from_all_media:
    my_list.add((row["id"],row["name"]))
```

Next overwrite the files one at a time:

```
for tsv in [tsv1, tsv2]:
    with open(tsv) as f_tsv:
        data = []
        for row in f_tsv:
            split = row.split('\t')[:2]    # first and second column values
            key = tuple(elt.strip() for elt in split)
            counts[key] += 1
            if key not in my_list:
                data.append(row)
    with open(tsv, 'w') as f_tsv:     # immediately overwrite in w mode
        for row in data:
            f_tsv.write(row)
```

Last but not least: as performance matters and as you already split the rows by hand, I assumed that you only have *clean and neat* fields with no tab or newlines in them. It there is a risk, you should forget manual parsing and use the csv module, which nicely handles that.

Comment: it gave me the following error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'add'` @Serge Ballesta

Comment: @ahmad: My bad. An empty set must be created as `set()`. `{}` creates an empy *dictionary*... Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by doing a left_outer merge on pandas:

To do so, first convert your list and tsv into DataFrames, and then drop the values in tsv coming DataFrames that are present in your list generated one. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load DataFrames
df_tsv1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/tsvfile1.tsv', sep='\t')
df_tsv2 = pd.read_csv('path/to/tsvfile2.tsv', sep='\t')
df_list = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

# Remove values that are present on list generated DataFrame
# Clean TSV1
df_clean_1 = pd.merge(dftsv, df, on=['id','name'], how="outer", indicator=True)
df_clean_1 = df_clean_1[df_clean_1['_merge'] == 'left_only']
# Clean TSV2
df_clean_2 = pd.merge(dftsv, df, on=['id','name'], how="outer", indicator=True)
df_clean_2 = df_clean_2[df_clean_2['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

Comment: it got me following error `raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'id'` @marsolmos